# Upload Music Playlist to website Using HTML

Tags: html, web, playlist

```
<embed name="PlayList" src="PlayList.m3u"
       width="300" height="75" loop="false" hidden="false"
       autostart="true">
</embed>
```

Here is how i did it:
1 Create an M3U file containing names of all songs that I already put on my server.
2 Using the HTML code to link that file as shown here.

While Nothing Happens....

This is how my m3u file look like:

Neo.mp3
In Christ Alone.wav

I just learnt HTML, so is there a method solving this using only HTML without Javascript or php?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to save the location to database and use php to access the value of location and put this code instead

Suppose you have  a table name playlist and column name location.

```
<?php$result=mysql_query("select * from playlist")
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{?>
<embed name="PlayList" src="<?php echo $rows['location']"
       width="300" height="75" loop="false" hidden="false"
       autostart="true">
</embed>
}
```

Now your embed look like

```
 <embed name="PlayList" src="Playlist.m3u"
        width="300" height="75" loop="false" hidden="false"
        autostart="true">
 </embed>
```